# Order of arithmetic operator execution C++

Tags: c++, math, operators, execution

In what order are the arithmetic operators (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,`%`) executed in C++? Is the standard BODMAS rule applicable here?
As an example, what would be the value of `m` here:

```
m = 605 / 10 + 45 % 7 + 29 % 11;
```

Comment: [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator precedence of C++ is the standard mathematical precedence, where `%` has the same precedence as `/`.

So, the expression `m = 605 / 10 + 45 % 7 + 29 % 11;` would be evaluated as

```
m = (605 / 10) + (45 % 7) + (29 % 11);
```

Which would result in:

```
m = (605 / 10) + (45 % 7) + (29 % 11);
m = 60 + 3 +7;
m = 70;
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a real answer to the question, but probably what OP wanted

Comment: @Slava "...what would the value of m here" "`m = 70;`" Looks like a well explained answer to me.

Comment: @scohe001 It does not explain order of arithmetic operator execution.

Answer (score 1):

In your expression, due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you could parse it to the following

```
m = (605 / 10) + (45 % 7) + (29 % 11);
```

In this case, the result would be `70`. The two things you should pay attention to are the *precedence* and the *associativity* (left to right vs right to left)

Answer (score 1):

The full order can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).
The / and % are first. Then the +. Like in math...

Answer (score 1):

*Marking this community wiki since this is information exists already in so many places... but might deserve a home here.*

With math operations, `*`, `/`, and `%` are applied first, left-to-right

`+` and `-` are then applied, also left-to-right

Cited from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

**Your `m` would be `70`.**